# HTTP absolute links being changed to HTTPS

Tags: asp.net, ssl, iis-6

https://alpha.pbp1.com/Property/Secure/test.htm

```
<a href="http://alpha.pbp1.com/Property/Default.aspx">Home</a>
```

This is a simple HTML page with a single href with the full absolute path to the website default page.

When viewed from within our company network it renders as expected, with HTTP in the href.
[alt text http://alpha.pbp1.com/img/testinternal.jpg](http://alpha.pbp1.com/img/testinternal.jpg)

But when viewed from a browser outside of our network it renders with HTTPS instead.
[alt text http://alpha.pbp1.com/img/testoutside.jpg](http://alpha.pbp1.com/img/testoutside.jpg)

This is a test environment, and I suspect that the SSL certificate may be part of the problem. Once we go beta it will have a real certificate but I think for now it is running on a generated one.

I would like for links that are coded with the full absolute path to keep the prefix that they were originally coded with. Any ideas on if this is IIS or the client replacing HTTP with HTTPS?
Running on Windows 2003, IIS6, ASP.NET2.0

Comment: You may have a proxy in the middle that rewrites http as https on ssl connections. Ask your network admins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have some sort of proxy before IIS hosting the webapp? I don't think IIS is issue. You can disable HTTPS (443) port on IIS and check. I am sure you will still get HTTPS.

Comment: Sounds about right, network admin is looking into it. I'll report back after confirmation/resolution

Comment: Network admin disabled "link translation" option on the firewall to fix this issue.